# How do I find the probability of this event?

Tags: probability

So let's say there's 3 people Rob, Jim, and Kyle. Let's say someone is randomly drawing names to give out two prizes. Rob has a 10% chance of winning prize 1. Kyle has a 30% chance of winning and Jim has a 60% chance. For prize 2, Rob has a 50% chance against Jim and a 35% chance against Kyle. Kyle has a 55% chance against Jim. So what is the probability that Rob will win a prize if we also consider the fact that both prizes can't be won by the same person. I'm starting out by trying to find the probability of Rob winning prize 2 in general because that's what's confusing me the most.

Comment: Does Rob just fight one person for prize two? Or does he fight both? Are fights independent of one another?

Comment: Also, if he fights just one, what are the probabilities that he squares up against a particular combatant?

Comment: It's just two prizes and only one prize 2. So that's what I'm confused about. I'm trying to figure out the chances that Rob will win prize two but he's being put up against two other people. So what I'm trying to figure out is the chances for each person so that if you just add up the probabilities for each person for prize 2 then it should add up to 100% but I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: I don't think the rules are clear.   Are all three competing for the first prize?  If so what are the probabilities for the other two players for the first one? That makes a huge difference.  If Rob loses the first one (as seems likely) he'd much prefer that Kyle win it.

Comment: I updated with more info for the other probabilities. So given those probabilities and the fact that there's only one prize 2 and only one prize 1 (and the same person can't win both prizes) what is the probability in general for each of the 3 people for prize 2?

Comment: Those probabilities do not make sense.  Since the winner of the first prize is out of the competition, the second is foungt by two players.  If it Rob and Kyle, then their respective probabilities must add to $1$.  Thus, if Rob has a $35\%$ shot against Kyle, Kyle must have a $65\%$ shot against Rob.  Is it possible that you meant to write "Kyle has a $55\%$ chance against JIM as well."?

Comment: @lulu I reckon that 55% must be Kyle against Jim?

Comment: Yes. I just updated the question so now Kyle has a 55% chance against Jim for prize 2.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:  to include Kyle and Jim, as requested in the comments.

ROB:
Ok, so Rob has three paths to victory:  He can win the first prize, he can beat Kyle for the second, or he can beat Jim for the second.  We just need to examine each.

Winning first prize:  probability = $\frac 1{10}$.

Beating Kyle on second round:  So Jim wins the first one (probability $\frac 6{10}$) but Rob then beats Kyle (probability $\frac {35}{100}$).  Thus Rob achieves victory along this path with probability $$\frac 6{10}*\frac {35}{100}=\frac {210}{1000}=\frac {21}{100}$$

Beating Jim on the second round: So Kyle wins the first one (probability $\frac 3{10}$) but Rob then beats Jim (probability $\frac {5}{10}$).  Thus Rob achieves victory along this path with probability $$\frac 3{10}*\frac {5}{10}=\frac {15}{100}$$.

Summing we get $$\frac {10}{100}+\frac {21}{100}+\frac {15}{100}=\boxed{\frac{46}{100}}$$

Working more quickly,

KYLE:

Wins the first with probability $\frac 3{10}$
Beats Rob for second:  Jim wins first ($\frac 6{10}$) then Kyle beats Rob ($\frac {65}{100}$)  Thus $\frac 6{10} * \frac {65}{100}=\frac {390}{1000}=\frac {39}{100}$
Beats Jim for second:  Rob wins first ($\frac 1{10}$) then Kyle beats Jim ($\frac {55}{100}$)  Thus $\frac 1{10} * \frac {55}{100}=\frac {55}{1000}$
In total:  $$\frac 3{10}+\frac {390}{1000}+\frac {55}{1000}=\boxed{\frac {745}{1000}}$$

JIM:

Wins the first with probability $\frac 6{10}$
Beats Rob for second:  Kyle wins first ($\frac 3{10}$) then Jim beats Rob ($\frac {5}{10}$)  Thus $\frac 3{10} * \frac {5}{10}=\frac {15}{100}$
Beats Kyle for second:  Rob wins first ($\frac 1{10}$) then Jim beats Kyle ($\frac {45}{100}$)  Thus $\frac 1{10} * \frac {45}{100}=\frac {45}{1000}$
In total:  $$\frac 6{10}+\frac {15}{100}+\frac {45}{1000}=\boxed{\frac {795}{1000}}$$

CONSISTENCY CHECK:

As two prizes are awarded, these ought to sum to $2$.  Let's check.  Adding the boxed probabilities we get $$\frac {460}{1000}+\frac {745}{1000}+\frac {795}{1000}=\frac {2000}{1000}=2$$

Comment: One more question is that so I tried calculating the probabilties for each person to just win prize 2. I got Rob = 36%, Kyle 39.5% and Jim 18.5%. The problem is I added all 3 percents together and got 94. So where's the missing 6%?

Comment: Why would you expect the probabilities to add to $1$?  there are $2$ prizes...the probabilities should add to $2$.  I'll work out Kyle and Jim and add it to the post.

Comment: On review, I see that I answered a slightly different question.  I worked out the probabilities that Kyle and Jim win any prize.  Of course this includes the calculation you asked for.  From the post you'll see that the probabilities that {Rob, Kyle, Jim} win the second prize are, respectively, $\{\frac {36}{100},\frac {445}{1000},\frac {195}{1000}\}$ and these add to $1$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Round 1:

All three can potentially win the prize.

$P($Rob wins prize 1$)=0.1$

$P($Jim wins prize 1$)=0.6$

$P($Kyle wins prize 1$)=0.3$

Round 2

If Rob has already won prize 1 then $P($Rob wins prize 2$)=0$. It doesn't matter whether Jim or Kyle wins prize 2.

If Jim has already won prize 1 then Rob is against Kyle so $P($Rob wins prize 2$)=0.35$

If Kyle has already won prize 1 then Rob is against Jim so $P($Rob wins prize 2$)=0.5$

Rob wins a prize if he wins prize 1 or if Jim wins prize 1 and Rob wins prize 2 or if Kyle wins prize 1 and Rob wins prize 2.

$P($Rob wins a prize$)=0.1 + 0.6 \times 0.35 + 0.3 \times 0.5 = 0.1 + 0.21 + 0.15  = 0.46$

Comment: What are you doing with prize 1? I updated my original question to show that Jim's probability for prize 1 is 60% and Kyle's is 30% (which works because all 3 add up to 100%). I also said that for prize 2, Jim and a 35% chance against Kyle.